# Parallax layout and z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index, parallax

I've a basic parallax layout which fundamentally seems to be working, but I'm struggling with the z-index of the static sections, which has caused them to scroll behind instead of in front of certain divs

HTML:

```
<header class="header">
  
</header>
<main class="parallax-container">
  <section class="parallax-section parallax-section--hero">
    HERO
  </section>
  <section class="static-section static-section--about">
    ABOUT
  </section>
  <section class="parallax-section parallax-section--testimonials">
    TESTIMONIALS
  </section>
   <section class="static-section static-section--footer">
    FOOTER
  </section>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body { 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.parallax-container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  // viewport of 100vh
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  // Set the perspective / simulate distance of children from the viewport
  perspective: 2px;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.parallax-section, .static-section {
  height: 100vh;
}

.parallax-section {
  // Allow the parallax section to be positioned in the 3d space
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  z-index: -1;
  
  &::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    background-image: url(https://asiamountains.net/upload/slide/slide-1960x857-07.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    // Move the pseudo element away from the camera and scale it up to fill the viewport
    transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(1.5);
    // Keep the images from overlapping siblings
    z-index: -1;
  }
}

.static-section {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  color: white;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

I've a codepen of the above problem set up [here](https://codepen.io/nwoodward/pen/dyGwWpK?editors=0100), you'll see the darkgrey static sections scroll behind the parallax background images. I've had this up and running correctly before, but I've just obviously made a mistake I can't spot. Z-index and stacking contexts always trip me up!

If anyone has the time to have a quick look it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `position:relative` to `static-section`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body { 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.parallax-container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  perspective: 2px;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.parallax-section, .static-section {
  height: 100vh;
}

.parallax-section {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  z-index: -1;
}
  
.parallax-section:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    background-image: url(https://asiamountains.net/upload/slide/slide-1960x857-07.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(1.5);
    z-index: -1;
  }

.static-section {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  
</header>
<main class="parallax-container">
  <section class="parallax-section parallax-section--hero">
    HERO
  </section>
  <section class="static-section static-section--about">
    ABOUT
  </section>
  <section class="parallax-section parallax-section--testimonials">
    TESTIMONIALS
  </section>
   <section class="static-section static-section--footer">
    FOOTER
  </section>
</main>
```

Does this solve your issue?

Comment: absolute. legend. 

thank you!

does specifying the position effect the stacking context that it belongs to or something?

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm not entirely sure. Whenever I have an issue with boxes overlapping, adding `position:relative` is my first go-to, because `position:static` is the default and `position:relative` generally keeps elements from overlapping each other and doesn't effect other elements' position. Glad it helped you though!

Comment: I'll keep that in mind next time I have a problem. And yeah, it really did, it's so nice when a problem doesn't drag out for the whole day - properly pleased!